# Finding a function that best fits another in an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm really confused about what this question is looking for:

Let $V$ be the $\mathbb R$-vector space of continuous functions over $[−1, 1]$ with inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t)dt$. Find the quartic (i.e. degree 4) polynomial $g(t)$ that best fits
the function $f(t) = cos(πt)$ over $[−1, 1]$.

What does it mean by a function that best fits the other?

Thanks

Comment: This is called best approximation of $f$ with functions from the linear subspace of degree four polynomials.

Comment: $g\in P_4$ is a best approximation of $f$ iff $\langle f-g,p\rangle =0,\,\forall p\in P_4$. This means $f-g$ should be perpendicular to each element from a basis of $P_4$

Answer (score 0):

The inner product as defined above induces a norm  on the functional vector space above:

$$ \|f\| := \sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}.$$

The question is asking you to find the polynomial $g$ that minimizes the norm $\|f-g\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Going one step further, find an orthonormal basis on $[-1,1]$ using Gram Schmidt, which will give you Legendre Polynomials. Then find the inner products (coefficients) upto degree 4.